# Convert values in column from hex to binary in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binary, hex

I have one column in pandas data frame with hex values, for example:

```
Data
1A
2B
BB
FF
A7
78
CB
```

I want to convert hex values in binary, then from binary to take first 3 bits and finally convert 3 bits value in decimal.

Data column in binary will be:

```
Data
00011010
00101011
10111011
11111111
10100111
01111000
11001011
```

the first 3 bits:

```
Data
010
011
011
111
111
000
011
```

and finally the desired value in decimal:

```
Data
2
3
3
7
7
0
3
```

How to do this? I tried with bin() function, but it doesn't work with pandas data frames.

Comment: Can you share your work so that it ll be easy for us to replicate.

Comment: I shared everything I could...I wish I could share more, but it is not allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do this by a chain of actions:

1. first we convert the hexadecimal number to an `int` with `.apply(int, base=16)`;
2. next we convert this to binary data, with `.apply(bin)`;
3. next we chunk off the first two characters with `.str[2:]`;
4. then we obtain the last three characters with `.str[-3:]`; and
5. finally we again interpret these as `int`s, with `.apply(int, base=2)`.

So:

```
>>> df.Data.apply(int, base=16).apply(bin).str[2:].str[-3:].apply(int, base=2)
0    2
1    3
2    3
3    7
4    7
5    0
6    3
Name: Data, dtype: int64
```

We can however use another strategy here:

1. we first convert the hexadecimal number to an `int`; and
2. then we apply a bitwise and with `0b111`.

for example:

```
>>> df.Data.apply(int, base=16) & 0b111
0    2
1    3
2    3
3    7
4    7
5    0
6    3
Name: Data, dtype: int64
```

The second attempt is not only simpler, but faster as well, approximately by 66%:

```
>>> timeit(first_strategy, number=10000)
6.962630775000434
>>> timeit(second_strategy, number=10000)
2.330652763019316
```

for a dataframe that repeats the sample data 100 times, we get:

```
>>> timeit(first_strategy, number=10000)
17.603060900000855
>>> timeit(second_strategy, number=10000)
5.901462858979357
```

this is again 66% faster.

Comment: I like the other strategy... I might be tempted to use `0b111` instead of `7` (or possibly `(1 << N) - 1` if it's going to be "the last `N` bits" where N is not just a couple ) or something but...

Comment: Thank you very much. It works...but if I have to extract 3 bits from the 2nd to 5th position in a byte (for example, from _"10010110"_ it is _"010"_), what I have to do? For the first solution, I could put **str[p1:p2]** and use **None** if it is the end of a string. But for the second solution, which by the way I like very much, how to extract bits that I want?

Comment: @slobokv83: you can first divide it by `(1<<2)` (so `4`), like `(df.Data.apply(int, base=16) // (1 << 2)) & 0b111`

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you. I have to shift to the position from which I want to get bits...and I have to add that in the first solution I modified it so the leading zeros are used and afterward is possible to extract from a position I want. Like: df.Data.apply(int, base=16).apply(bin).str[2:].str.zfill(width).str[-p1:p2].apply(int, base=2)

Comment: @slobokv83: well as said, you can use `(df.Data.apply(int, base=16) // (1 << o)) & ((1 << w) - 1)` to obtain the values between the bits `o` and `o+w`, no need to slice, zfill`, etc.

Comment: That is all that I need. Thank you very much. Very simple and fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df.Data.apply(lambda v: int(format(int(v, 16), '08b')[-3:], 2))
```

Which gives you:

```
0    2
1    3
2    3
3    7
4    7
5    0
6    3
Name: Data, dtype: int64
```

Those steps are:

- Take your original data and convert it to decimal using `int(number, 16)` (base 16 is hex) (`int('1A', 16)` == `26`)
- Take that number and format it as a binary string `format(number, '08b')` gives you an character string of 0/1's zero filled on the left (`format(26, '08b')` == `'00011010'`)
- Take the last 3 characters of that string `[-3:]` (`'010'`) and convert it to decimal with a base 2, `int(binary_string[-3:], 2)` gives you: `2`

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine...I have another question - if I need for the length of the bits array to be variable, what I have to do? You put _'08b'_, and if I want in some moment to be _'16b'_, should I put like _'{length}b'_ and for length give some value?